# How to separate cc and bcc in messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, messaging, has-many-through

I'm currently trying to develop a messaging system for my website.

So far the file look like this:

/app/models/user.rb

```
has_many :user_chats
has_many :chats, :through => :user_chats
has_many :messages, :through => :chats
```

/app/models/user_chat.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :chat
has_many :messages, :through => :chats
```

/app/models/chat.rb

```
has_many :user_chats
has_many :users, :through => :user_chats
has_many :messages
```

So now I can get all users participating in a chat via @chat.users

But how can I separate two groups of users? to recipients and bcc recipients.

I thought about adding a bbc:boolean to the user_chat model. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would too add a boolean `bcc` flag to your `UserChat` model, that is one of the advantages using **has_many_through** associations over **has_and_belongs_to_many**.

---

**Removed invalid answer**

Comment: Alright, thanks! I've just been trying around and ran into another problem. How would you set the flag? Currently I'm adding users to a conversation via `conversation.user_ids = ids`. `ids` is an Array of user ids.

Comment: Btw try to use Ruby 1.9 hash syntax. It's so much easier to read: `has_many :bbc_users, through: :user_chats, conditions: { bbc: true }`

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. `has_many :bcc_users, through: :user_chats, conditions: { bcc: true }, source: :user` throws an error: `ERROR:  column users.bcc does not exist`. I have to set the source otherwise it's not working. Any ideas?